# Find out where iOS user is from, for Sina Weibo integration?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, social-framework

I want to integrate posting to Sina Weibo in my app for Chinese users, but I don't want the option to appear for the majority of my users who won't even know what Sina Weibo is. Is there a way that I can find out whether the user is chinese or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to figure out if a user is chinese. So you should use [`isAvailableForServiceType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/isAvailableForServiceType%3a).

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo]) {
    // sina weibo is available, and at least one account is set up
}
else {
    // sina weibo is not available, or no accounts are set up
}
```